# How to get list of users in a server

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm wondering how to obtain a list of user ids in my server when using discord.js. I've been searching around a lot but couldn't find anything that really worked. Would appreciate anyone's help.

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation ? https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=fetchMembers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`Guild.members`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=member) is a `Collection<Snowflake, GuildMember>` which extends Map so you should be able to iterate through the key values like this

```
for (let [snowflake, guildMember] of mems) {
  console.log('snowflake: ' + snowflake);
  console.log('id: ' + guildMember.id);
  console.log('user id: ' + guildMember.user.id);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Should this line of code work to first get the guild members? var mems = client.guilds.get("My channel id").members;

Comment: So here you are provided guilds not channels, therefore `var mems = client.guilds.get("Your guild id").members` to get the collection of members.

Comment: Oh yes, meant to say guild id not channel id :) It works now, thanks.

Comment: But watch out Guild#members only Container chached members