# Get the list of all user on a server discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to get all users from my server with a bot using discord.js, I wrote this code but it's not working, it's telling me : `TypeError: client.guilds.get is not a function`. Here is my code :

```
'use strict';
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
const list = client.guilds.get("myServerID"); 
list.members.forEach(member => console.log(member.user.username)); 
client.login('myTokenID');
```

Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53752304/how-to-get-list-of-users-in-a-server

Comment: @VedantBang please refrain from randomly chucking unrelated links to solve people's questions, your second link was a C# related Q&A not JavaScript

Comment: I'm sorry, I made a misclick there.

Answer (score 5):

#### **Update ( 25 Feb 2023 ):**

For discord v14+,

1. Make sure you have `GatewayIntentBits.GuildMembers` or something like this to intents.
2. Before using `guild.members.cache`, call guild.members.fetch() atleast once. I think subsequent calls can be made using cache.

```js
const client = new Client({
    intents: [
        GatewayIntentBits.GuildMembers,  // MAKE SURE TO ADD THIS
    ],
});


client.on(Events.ClientReady, async (client) => {
    console.log("client ready");
    const guild = client.guilds.cache.get("<guild_id>");

    console.log("fetching users");
    let res = await guild.members.fetch();
    res.forEach((member) => {
        console.log(member.user.username);
    });
})
```

---

Since discord.js v12,

you now need to access the `guilds` collection using `.cache` and I can also see that you're trying to access the `members` collection so your solution would be:

```js
'use strict';
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
const list = client.guilds.cache.get("myServerID"); 
list.members.cache.forEach(member => console.log(member.user.username)); 
client.login('myTokenID');
```

Comment: It seems to list only connected members ... Can you confirm ? Is that a solution to get a full list, even not connected members ?

Comment: @xNiux use `Guild.members.fetch()` to fetch all members, even offline ones.

Answer (score 1):

just use `.fetch()`

```js
const guild = await client.guilds.fetch('your_id')
const members = await guild.members.fetch() // returns Collection
```